# React dyanmically "instantiate" new elements of the same kind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's consider this mouse event:

```
function onMouseUp(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isText) {
        mouseSelRect.current.style.left = x1 + 'px';
        mouseSelRect.current.style.top = x2 + 'px';
        mouseSelRect.current.style.width = x3 + 'px';
        mouseSelRect.current.style.height = x4 + 'px';
        createTextArea(x1, x2, x3, x4);
      }
}
```

I want to create multiple "instances" per se of textareas every time i make a select rectangle and release the mouse, with the select rectangle created, i can customize the dimensions of a new textArea. The main problem with web developing, however is that the environment heavily encourages being as "declare all elements that you need before rendering page" as possible.

I would like to know if it is even possible to create out of a event a new element that is not necessarily on the return part of a hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the createTextArea function can return a component and you can maybe add the component to a list of components (a state, for example)

```
const List = () => {
  const [componentList, setComponentList] = React.useState([])
  const onMouseUp = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (isText) {
            mouseSelRect.current.style.left = x1 + 'px';
            mouseSelRect.current.style.top = x2 + 'px';
            mouseSelRect.current.style.width = x3 + 'px';
            mouseSelRect.current.style.height = x4 + 'px';
            const component = createTextArea(x1, x2, x3, x4);
            setComponentList([...componentList, component])
          }
    }

  return (
    <div>{componentList.map(Component => <Component />)}</div>
  )
}
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do with the components list, but in the example above I just rendered it. But you can use the array to do whatever you want to.

Comment: Basically i can use the list so the user can make multiple textareas that they can create based on how big they wanted it to be. The user can also change the fonts and text format for the current textArea they are active on.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to create new elements and trigger a re-render of the page to include those elements.  That's what the framework is intended for: dynamic page content that responds to changes in state.  (Check https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_intro.asp or elsewhere for introductory material that will demonstrate it.)

Comment: I absolutely had a different introduction to WebDev as i was educated into software dev and had to enter self-teach React out of work market necessity.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the non-react portion of my answer.  But you should probably accept neto's answer above, as I think that is the closest most useful answer for the question!